# What is the meaning of the end of "Copenhagen Cowboy"?

Tags: copenhagen-cowboy

In the last episode of *Copenhagen Cowboy*, things seem reasonably coherent right until Miu fulfills her deal with Chiang and the latter returns his and Mother Huldra's daughter to Mother Huldra.

However, then things start to get weird. After Miu gets into a martial arts match with Chiang, possibly inside Chiang's mind, we then cut to her gathering a large number of women wearing identical blue tracksuits, who form a circle. After this, Niklas's sister (who lives in a coffin and has just eaten the heart of a...forest-dwelling businessman?) screams like a banshee from her doorstep, which apparently hurts Miu wherever she is, and then her eyes light up like Superman and she fires her eye beams at...something. We then cut to Miroslav talking to some random contact of his, who confidently informs him that apparently, only the Giants can fight Miu.

What, exactly, is happening in the final episode of *Copenhagen Cowboy*? What does it all mean?